# MySQL ORDER BY COUNT()?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table setup in my database with this structure:

[image: table-structure]

I have running a query through a while loop and I want to order by the count of the prof column.

This is what my query currently looks like, though I keep getting errors.

```
$order_list = mysql_query("
    SELECT COUNT(prof), 
    FROM prof_rating 
    ORDER BY COUNT(prof) ASC");
```

This is the warning I keep getting.

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For what it's worth, any use of an aggregate function in the select-list means that the result set will have only one row.  It makes little sense to sort a results set with a single row.

If you meant to get a count of ratings per distinct value of prof, you should use this:

```
$order_list = mysql_query("
    SELECT prof, COUNT(*) AS PROFCOUNT, 
    FROM prof_rating 
    GROUP BY prof
    ORDER BY PROFCOUNT ASC'");
```

That will output multiple rows, one row per prof value, with the count of rows for each given prof value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Realized at the core what the problem was, I had an extra ' in my mysql_query and it was causing the warning message. Can't believe I overlooked it at first.

Answer (score 6):

Alias the column name and then put that in your order by clause :)

```
$order_list = mysql_query("
SELECT COUNT(prof) AS PROFCOUNT, 
FROM prof_rating 
ORDER BY PROFCOUNT ASC'");
```